# Where are the default snippets for C++ stored in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

So I've been using VS Code for a while now and I noticed that for some reason it started having extra snippets which I did not make come up in options, while they are useful I would like to edit them to my personal code formatting style.

I've tried looking for the `json` file which holds them however I am unable to locate it anywhere. I figured it would be in my install directory however the `cpp.json` file there simply defines the `#pragma region` snippet only.

For reference I looked in this location: `C:\Users\Rietty\AppData\Local\Programs\VSCode\resources\app\extensions\cpp\snippets`

A difference to show the two snippets is like so: [image: snippet example] and my user defined one which is marked with a `user snippet` next to the description.

I also got many new `for` loops and so on and so forth:

[image: loops]

Where can I find the location of these new snippets so I can edit them to my standards/formatting style?

**Update:**

I spent a decent bit looking this up and it seems the reason for this is due to the [VSCode CPP Tools extension.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools) Recent changes indicate that this occurred due to moving snippets to the hard-coded lexer from the relevant `json` file and that it is currently intended.

However an issue was already filed and is hopefully slated to be fixed sometime [February 2019.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3083)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in [release 0.22.0 of Visual Studio Code - CPP Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/releases/tag/0.22.0) with the release of the `suggestSnippets` setting. Now you don't have to worry about duplicating snippets due to the language server and can only use your hand made ones.

To change this setting:

- Click Ctrl+Shift+P and type in "view: show extensions".
- Open the C/C++ extension by Microsoft
- Click the gear, then "Extension Settings"
- Type "Suggest Snippets"
- Deselect the box "If true, snippets are provided by the language server".

Comment: But it will be nice to know the location of those default snippets

Comment: @Slye AFAIK They're built into VSCode/The language server.